# Scala tests with Either and Pattern Matching best practice

Tags: scala, testing, junit

I want to test my method which returns an Either. This is how i do this:

```
@Test def `Test empty name is not valid`: Unit = {
    val book = createBook()
    val result = insertEntryToBook(book, "", "12345")

    result match {
      case Left(InvalidNameFormat) => true
      case _ => fail()
    }
  }
```

Should i do some assert() call instead of fail() to make the test's fail message more explicit (e.g. for assertion side-to-side view)?

Comment: Yes you should create two separete test to check "positive" and "negative" ways. For now, your test is not deterministic and could return different results. Also for checking results use assertions.

Comment: But what about complicated cases? For example, when i need to parse json to some class first and there is generated fields like uuids?

Comment: The best way is to prepare `test suites` for given examples. Your test should be deterministic (for same input, always return same value). You should not put random data in specific test scenario. Try use `ScalaTest` and prepare some test scenarios for given input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ScalaTest [can be used with JUnit](http://www.scalatest.org/getting_started_with_junit_4_in_scala), so consider mixing in [`EitherValues`](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_EitherValues) which should give more informative messages

```
import org.junit.Test
import org.scalatest.{EitherValues, Matchers}

class ExampleSuite extends Matchers with EitherValues {
  @Test def matchEithers(): Unit = {
    val result: Either[String, Int] = Right(42)
    result.left.value should be ("Boom")
  }
}
```

which gives

```
org.scalatest.exceptions.TestFailedException: The Either on which left.value was invoked was not defined as a Left.

    at org.scalatest.EitherValues$LeftValuable.value(EitherValues.scala:124)
    at example.ExampleSuite.matchEithers(ExampleSuite.scala:9)
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to pattern match here. You can just assert the result equals the expected value wrapped in a `Left()`.

```
assertEquals(Left(InvalidNameFormat), result)
```

In case your test fails, you get a precise error message.